# natural-language-process and nlp

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I've noticed that there is a tag called `natural-language-process` that has been used more than 170 times already.

Should it be made a synonym of the [nlp](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp) tag which has been used 10x more often?

Comment: I see that its already a [synonym](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tags/nlp/synonyms). Do upvote if you think approproate